# Not able to get the message from remote MQ

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I can connect to remote MQ using my code but cant able to get the message from remote MQ .  Im getting error like System.TypeInitializationException in 
queueGetMessageOptions [b].

Please help any clue regarding will do fine or any documentation will do fine

[image]

My C# code like this

```
  namespace MQMessageSender
  {
      public class MQTest
      {
           public static void Main()
           {
               ConnectMQ();

           }

           public static int ConnectMQ()
           {
              MQQueueManager queueManager;

              MQMessage queueMessage;
              // MQPutMessageOptions queuePutMessageOptions;
              MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;
              MQQueue queue;
              // Hashtable properties;
              // MQMessage message;

              string QueueName;
              string QueueManagerName;
              string ChannelInfo;
              string channelName;
              string PortNumber;
              string transportType;
              string connectionName;
              //string message;

              QueueManagerName = "*****";
              QueueName = "*******";
              ChannelInfo = "****/*****/*****/*****";
              PortNumber = "****";


              char[] separator = { '/' };
              string[] ChannelParams;
              ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);
              channelName = "*****";
              transportType = "MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT";
              connectionName = "*****(****)";
              String strReturn = "";

              try
              {
                  queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,
                  channelName, connectionName);
                  strReturn = "Connected Successfully";

                  queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
                  MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                  queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                  queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                  queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                  queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
                  strReturn = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
            }
            catch (MQException exp)
            {
                 strReturn = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
            }

           Console.WriteLine(strReturn);
           Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
           Console.ReadLine();
           return 0;
       }
```

Error :

The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post picture. Post your actual code and an error message. There is message options - can't see in picture.

Comment: saha.jan if the queue you are trying to open is of type QREMOTE, then you can not open it for input.  Also please do not add the tag [[tag:ibmmqcloud]] to your questions since it is not a IBM MQ Cloud offering that you are asking about.  The tag [[tag:ibm-mq]] is fine for these questions.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for reply :) .. I want to get the message from MQ but getting error in  queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions); Can you tell me the error ..what to do to fix this??

Comment: There is something wrong in your configuration file. The exception tells "unrecognized configuration section param".

Comment: @subbaraoc yes you are right . There was some mistake regarding type configuration . I can see the remote messages . many many many thanks :D :D

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your configuration file. The exception tells "unrecognized configuration section param"